# What is an ideal approach for learning Android Development for C# developer?

Tags: c#, android, .net

I am a .NET developer and I love coding in C#.

I want to learn Android Development and wondering what is the ideal approach for learning Android Development, specially for a developer who does not know Java and has good knowledge of C#.

Can you suggest me any books, tutorials, approach?

Comment: http://monodevelop.com/Download/Mono_For_Android? :P (Only if you really want to stay with C#, though I'd honestly recommend trying to learn Android Java programming).

Comment: Complete Android from starting : http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6

Comment: [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/index.html)

Comment: Mono for android is not that gud idea learn from strach and see what is android and like wise.. video are good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even use C# for Android development, see the references:

1. [Create amazing Android apps with C# and .NET](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid)
2. [Android for the Visual Studio C# developer](http://www.wroolie.co.uk/2012/06/android-for-the-visual-studio-c-developer/)
3. [Building Android Applications using C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/building-android-applications-using-C-Sharp)